# pygal rendering series as hidden

Tags: python, pygal

when I generate a chart into svg in pygal, it allows to click in legend and hide a series. How can I generate graph with series hidden and user only choosing which ones to see? Ideally if there I can choose each series to be hidden or shown upon generation.

Apologies if this is a simple question, but I am struggling to find an answer.

Thank you,
Tomas

Comment: To sort of close the loop here. I have not found a way to achieve above in pygal. That said, in general, I found pygal very easy to use, but with its limitation. In the end, I have learned to work with bokeh, which allowed me to create buttons that are hiding series across multiple charts on a same page.